# UPDATE mysql nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

So i have this array from my local host

```
{
"idmovielist": 6,
"name": "Lion King",
"thumnail_path": "https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/",
"description": "cartoon",
"year_released": "1994",
"language_released": "english"
},
```

I wanna change the year_released based on my idmovielist
this is what I have

```
app.put('/movielist/upddate/:id',(req,res) =>{
let update = req.body;
mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET year_released = '2000' WHERE idmovielist = '6'",
[update.year_released, update.idmovielist,req.params.id],
(err, results)  => {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
});
});
and
```

when I do this it does not update note: I am writing in the hard coded values
http://localhost:3000/movielist
this is where I got the list from

```
$.ajax({
    method:"PUT",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/update/6",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        idmovielist: 6,
        name: 'Lion King',
        thumanail_path: 'https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/',
        description: 'cartoon',
        year_realeased: '2000',
        language_released: 'english'
    },
    success: function (data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, movie) {
       const rowText = "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
        $("#movies").append(rowText);
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: How are you issuing the 'PUT' request to `/movielist/upddate/:id`? curl? postman? some other application? What is the input and output to that app when you make the HTTP `PUT` request?

Comment: @Richard my local host and my front end site

Comment: Can we see the code that executes this request?

Comment: @Richard just posted it

Comment: When you trigger the ajax request, what does the [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) say?